# Unexpected rectangle symbol at char array java

Tags: java, arrays, character

My program is about to sort the input text to a-z and count every letter in the text. So if someone's input is "Lorem Ispum Dolor Amet", the output will be "   adileelmmmoooprrstu" and "a=1, d=1, e=2, i=1, l=2, m=3, o=3, p=1, r=2, s=1, t=1, u=1";

So I have the input text in the char array.
However, when I'm trying my code, it outputs a rectangle symbol.

> Input:"Lorem Ispum Dolor Amet"
>
> Output:"    adileelmmmoooprrstu"(with rectangle symbol at start)

The input variable is Character object, so I've tried this:

```
if((input.charValue()<65 && input.charValue()> 90) &&
                (input.charValue() < 97 && input.charValue() > 122)) continue;
```

and this: `if(input==' ' || input==' ') continue;`(if input is space or rectangle)

However, it is not working(it works with space, I cant filter rectangle)

How can I avoid this and why there is rectangle symbol as the first char in char array?

Comment: Not entirely sure why since you haven't uploaded all your code, but you could remove the rectangle symbol at the start by using `output.substring(1);`

Comment: It would have been smarter to show *all* the code. Were you trying to play mystery chasers with us?

Comment: BOM was the reason.

Answer (score 2):

This condition

```
if((input.charValue()<65 && input.charValue()> 90) &&
            (input.charValue() < 97 && input.charValue() > 122)) continue;
```

will always be false, as char value can not be both < 65 and >90. Most likely once you fix the filtering condition, the issue with rectangle character will disappear.